# How to Create Multiple Newlines in Html

Tags: html, css, newline

In normal HTML you would use the `br` tag but if I would like to do ***20+ newlines*** it would look very messy. I would like to do this with minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop with Javascript or your backend language (Php,...).

```js
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    text += "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
Top
<p id="demo"></p>
Bottom
```

But if you just need to *add some space*, you would prefer using CSS `padding` or `margin`:

```css
div{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>Top</div>
<div>Bottom</div>
```